# Javascript - window.open 'location=no' still shows addressbar in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, window.open

I'm opening a window using [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open) and setting location parameter to no.  In IE9 the location/addressbar doesn't show, however in Firefox it is still shown. Why does Firefox still show location bar even when I say 'location=no'?

Comment: I think that IE 9 only allows that when testing locally, not for an untrusted domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's  up to the useragent to determine which functionality to support.  It seems (and rightfully so) that firefox deemed it a security problem to disable address bar.  There is likely an about:config to turn it on, but I definitely wouldn't count on the "hiding address bar" functionality to be cross browser.

EDIT: actually in your linked article: `dom.disable_window_open_feature.location` defaults to true in firefox 3 (search under "location" section)

Comment: so does dom.disable_window_open_feature.location mean that location parameter can't be modified?

Comment: For users that have that value set (practically everyone since it is default) the location parameter is ignored for `window.open`